# Can I get these metrics with JMX from OpenDJ?

Tags: active-directory, directory, directoryservices, opends, opendj

-concurrent connections
- unindexed searches count
- replication status

I used jconsole but I didn't seem to find them. Do I need to use LDAP-based monitoring for that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

All statistics available through LDAP are also available through JMX.
I don't think there is such thing as the unindexed search count though.
And the replication status is not a simple value such as ok, degraded, nok. But the complete information is available through JMX as well.